# In VIM how to replace <word>->abc to ABC(<word>) for all possible values of <word>

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

So, I have a big code file in C, in which there are multiple dereferences like this.

```
iter->sector;
msg->sector;
dump.msg->sector;
```

where the type of iter and msg is same. Now, due to some changes, I've had to write a macro, to replace these lines. The macro looks like,

```
DUMMY_MACRO(iter)
DUMMY_MACRO(msg)
DUMMY_MACRO(dump.msg)
```

What I want is to be able to do the replacement of the earlier code to the new macro code using vim search/replace.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you. This is a simple search-and-replace; `:help :s` and `:help \1` should be all you need.

Comment: I did not know about \1, had tried doing a search and replace for the whole string for each different line having ->sector, which was suboptimal. Since that was kinda obviously not right, I did not post it here. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case  you already know `sed`, then `:substitute` will be the perfect tool.

```
" untested
:%s/\v(\S+)-\>sector/DUMMY_MACRO(\1)/g

:h :s
:h /\v   " -> to simplify expressions
:h /\(   " -> define a group
:h /\S   " -> any thing that is not a space
:h /\+   " -> 1 or more 
:h /\1   " -> ref to 1st group
```